# XNA Where to begin?

Tags: xna

I am going to look into XNA But i dont know where to start. What book will you recomand? is there a site with tutorials of some kind?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Well, the official site has plenty tutorials and samples:

- [Education Catalog (samples, etc...)](http://xbox.create.msdn.com/en-US/education/catalog/)

And there is the Getting Started section:

- [Getting Started](http://xbox.create.msdn.com/en-us/home/getting_started)

Comment: Note: I've updated the links, they now point to the 'Xbox Live Indy Games' part of the doc, which is relevant for any XNA development (Windows/Xbox360/Windows Phone 7).

Answer (score 5):

I've found that the [Riemers](http://www.riemers.net/) tutorial is pretty helpful, at least to give you a decent starting foundation.

Answer (score 4):

The XNA Dev Center is the place to go:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/aa937791.aspx

Answer (score 2):

If you are making a simple 2d game, I'd recommend checking out the Flat Red Ball engine.  It's a fantastic 2d engine with XBOX, PC, Windows Phone, and Silverlight compatibility.  They have fantastic support.  It's free.   (No, I do not have any affiliation with FRB, have just been using their engine for over a year.)

XNA is a great platform, but not an engine.  The XNA tutorials are great, but do not fit into an object-component model like FRB does.